# When Would a Fetch Request's Credentials Mode be Include?

Tags: browser, cors, fetch, access-control

I'm looking at implementing the necessary handling for CORS on a Device which exposes a basic HTTP server for control. In order to define how the Device should respond I've found myself attempting to understand just how the browser would be configured to perform the requests. In particular, I'm trying to better understand the behaviour of a browser around Fetch's Request `credentials` mode (and to a lesser extent `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`).

I'm aware that it would be problematic for the Device to respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` if the Initial Server has set the request's credentials mode to be `include`. This is per the [table here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials).

I don't quite understand when / why the Initial Server would actually set this mode.
Is this...

1. a flag to the browser so its aware the Initial Server has explicitly added credentials in its request to Device
2. a request to the browser's internal mechanisms to find any credentials for Device it has stored, and to include them in the CORS Request
3. a request to the browser's internal mechanisms to forward on any credentials it has used when talking to Initial Server onto the Device
4. other (?)

I'm assuming its intended for enabling option 2 due to the reference to the Confused Deputy problem in the above link but my knowledge of browser behaviour is non-existent.

If there were certain URIs on Device which required an `Authorization` header, would that have a definitive effect on the value of the credentials mode specified with the request (even if I *assume* the Initial Server was likely to be the one specifying the value for that header)? This is of interest, as I believe if `include` mode is required for these paths, then this would necessitate the addition of a `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header on the CORS Response.

The following diagram is just an overview of the expected interactions. Its assumed the CORS Preflight request is necessary for the resources being retrieved.

```
Browser          Initial Server             Device
   |                   |                       |
   |  GET              |                       |
   | ----------------> |                       |
   |                   |                       |
   | Also GET Device   |                       |
   | <---------------- |                       |
   |                   |                       |
   | CORS Preflight Request (OPTIONS)          |
   | ----------------------------------------> |
   |                   |                       |
   | CORS Preflight Response                   |
   | <---------------------------------------- |
   |                   |                       |
   | CORS Request (GET)                        |
   | ----------------------------------------> |
   |                   |                       |
   | CORS Response                             |
   | <---------------------------------------- |
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: *` is invalid. The only header value that has any effect is `true`.

Comment: The answer is 2. By setting the request's `credentials` property to `include`, you're instructing the browser to attach any _ambient authority_ (Basic credentials, cookies, client certificates, etc.) that it has and is associated to the request's destination origin.